# How do I implement a struct that takes a generic vector with lifetime annotations?

Tags: rust

The following compiles fine:

```rust
pub struct Reader<'a> {
    position: uint,
    data: &'a [u8]
}
```

It's a reader that takes a vector (actually a slice) of type `u8` as a reference, and I specify the lifetime.

However this is not exactly what I want. I want to be able to make the struct generic, and to be even more precise, I want to denote that the type should be a slice of anything. I tried this for starters:

```rust
pub struct Reader<'a, T> {
    position: uint,
    data: &'a T
}
```

It does not denote `T` to be a slice, but this is already failing with a message:

> the parameter type `T` may not live long enough; consider adding an
>   explicit lifetime bound `T:'a`...

Ok so I just had to specify the lifetime.

But now my problem is that how do I make it generic of type slice and have the lifetime? I tried things like `Reader<'a, T: 'a Vec>` and `T: 'a [T]` but I have no idea how I am supposed to denote this and the official guide does not seem to deal with a case like this.

I simply want to construct a Reader that takes in any type of slice by borrowing it, and provides methods to operate on the data (in read-only ways).

Answer (score 37, accepted):

After trying a bit more, I finally figured it out:

```rust
pub struct Reader<'a, T> {
    position: uint,
    data: &'a [T]
}
```

This defines the reader's `data` to be of type `Slice<T>` (`[]` denotes the slice) and `&'a` specifies the lifetime for the borrowed data.

Now I can implement stuff like this:

```rust
impl<'a, T> Reader<'a, T> {
    pub fn from_data(bytes: &'a[T]) -> Reader<'a, T> {
        Reader {
            position: 0,
            data: bytes
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Very helpful! Thanks for post your solution!

Comment: Why do you require `T: 'a`? Maybe it was required back in 2014, but not now anymore? It compiles without it: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=9d4058d66f152f9f6e94d19d3258058f

Answer (score 13):

Not intending to answer directly, it's just that I came across this SO answer when I was looking for an answer to my own problem: How to apply a generic type constraint and a lifetime constraint to a struct's field.

(Here's the working solution I came up with.)

```
use std::io::Writer;

// This specifies lifetime constraint of 'a
// Type W must implement the Writer trait
// Type W has the lifetime 'a (the same as the related struct instance)
pub struct Foo<'a, W: 'a + Writer> {
    writer: &'a mut W
}
```